# Adding an old version of Ocaml to Opam

Tags: package, switch-statement, ocaml, coq, opam

I am trying to install Coq version 8.10.2 using Opam and from this output, I assume Coq 8.10.2 needs an ocaml compiler with version < 4.10

```
Missing dependency:
    - (invariant) -> coq = 8.10.2 -> ocaml < 4.10 -> ocaml-base-compiler < 3.07+1 | ocaml-system < 3.07+1 | ocaml-variants < 3.8~
    unmet availability conditions: 'arch != "arm64" & arch != "arm32" & arch != "ppc64"'
    unmet availability conditions: 'sys-ocaml-version = "3.07"'
    no matching version
.
.
.
  * Missing dependency:
    - (invariant) -> coq = 8.10.2 -> ocaml < 4.10 -> ocaml-base-compiler = 4.09.2 | ocaml-system >= 4.09.2 | ocaml-variants < 4.09.3~
    no matching version
    unmet availability conditions, e.g. 'sys-ocaml-version = "4.14.0"'
    unmet availability conditions, e.g. '!(os = "macos" & arch = "arm64")'
```

and the problem is that ocaml with version < 4.10 is not available in opam's list of packages. Running **opam switch list-available base** prints this output

```
# Listing available compilers from repositories: default
# Name              # Version     # Synopsis
ocaml-base-compiler 4.10.2        Official release 4.10.2
ocaml-base-compiler 4.12.0~alpha1 First alpha release of OCaml 4.12.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.12.0~alpha2 Second alpha release of OCaml 4.12.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.12.0~alpha3 Third alpha release of OCaml 4.12.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.12.0~beta1  First beta release of OCaml 4.12.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.12.0~beta2  Second beta release of OCaml 4.12.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.12.0~rc1    First release candidate of OCaml 4.12.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.12.0        Official release 4.12.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.12.1        Official release 4.12.1
ocaml-base-compiler 4.13.0~alpha1 First alpha release of OCaml 4.13.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.13.0~alpha2 Second alpha release of OCaml 4.13.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.13.0~beta1  First beta release of OCaml 4.13.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.13.0~rc1    First release candidate of OCaml 4.13.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.13.0~rc2    Second release candidate of OCaml 4.13.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.13.0        Official release 4.13.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.13.1        Official release 4.13.1
ocaml-base-compiler 4.14.0~alpha1 First alpha release of OCaml 4.14.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.14.0~alpha2 Second alpha release of OCaml 4.14.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.14.0~beta1  First beta release of OCaml 4.14.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.14.0~rc1    First release candidate of OCaml 4.14.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.14.0~rc2    Second release candidate of OCaml 4.14.0
ocaml-base-compiler 4.14.0        Official release 4.14.0
```

I want to use Opam because I need to switch to different version of Coq for other project. Is there a way I can add an ocaml version < 4.10 to opam?

Comment: Little bit of an XY problem aroma to this. Why is the old version of Coq needed? Perhaps there is a workaround there.

Answer (score 4):

### How to install a specific version of OCaml?

To install a different version of OCaml, you need to create a new switch, e.g.,

```
opam switch create 3.12.0
```

Will install the corresponding version of OCaml. To get the list of available versions of OCaml, use,

```
opam switch list-available
```

### Why is version N not available on my system?

From the error message, I can see that your system is an ARM64 macOS, and the specifications of the older versions of the OCaml package explicitly [specify](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/blob/aab873590886cf4d96a023c52ad5528fde9a88e7/packages/ocaml-base-compiler/ocaml-base-compiler.4.09.0/opam#L48) that they are [not available](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/pull/17716) on that system,

```
available: !(os = "macos" & arch = "arm64")
```

So the oldest version that is available for your architecture is 4.10.1. I can only suggest using a virtual machine, docker, or another physical machine.

Comment: The problem seems to be that old versions of OCaml don't show up on OP's system.

Comment: As @Li-yaoXia mentioned, ocaml 3.12.0 does not show up in the output of "opam switch list-available", so running "spam switch create 3.12.0" returns a similar missing dependency error

Comment: Yes, @Li-yaoXia is right and I have updated the answer.